# Is there a way to import c dlls and header files in powershell?

Tags: powershell, marshalling, add-type

Is there a way to import C DLLs and header files in PowerShell?
I was not able to get `Add-Type` to work.

Comment: See P/Invoke in PowerShell: https://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2009/01/19/powershell-pinvoke-walkthrough/

Comment: "I was not able to get Add-Type to work." maybe if you show us what you tried we can help you fix it :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen

This is what I tried:

```[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($dllName) | Out-Null```

Error: Could not load file or assembly 'dllName' or one of its 
dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest."

I get the same error if I use Add-Type.

Comment: this is too broad. Different parameters need different ways to marshal depending, for example `char*` can be marshalled as `String` or `StringBuilder`. There's no way to answer without any code